# Class C address reachable on iOS over mobile

Tags: ios, reachability

I am implementing network reachability in my iOS app. My server has a class C ip address **192.168.x.x.**

When both wifi an 3G are turn on my device. The reachability flags tells me that the destination is reachable via wifi.

When i turn wifi off on the device but keep 3G on, the network reachability flags tell me that the destination is reachable via mobile as well.

My understanding is that this is not possible as my server is not publicly avialable on the internet.

Is it possible the gateway for the mobile service provider has a server internally with that IP, or it is somehow always falsely saying that the IP address is reachable. I am on the O2 network in the UK.

Just incase it was a problem with my app I also got the same result with the apple example application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system doesn't know if you can connect to a particular IP (without actually connecting to it and succeed/fail). It knows whether your devices have a network connectivity or not.

If you are connected to the internet you can establish connections to any IP addresses, even in private range. The fact that such a connection will likely fail is another thing.

A remote host is considered reachable when a data packet, sent by an application into the network stack, can leave the local device.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Mirek, but I'm slightly confused. What is the point of providing a hostname or IP address to network reachability. Does it not try to reach that addreess to determine whether there is a path to it?

Comment: The point is that the Reachability API can return back if you can actually attempt to connect to the IP/host. Like if you have a valid IP routing entry for the destination and if your DNS is working and your network interface is up. It is common for public Wifi hotspots to block internet access until the user authenticates via web interface. Or you can be connected to a peer-peer only. In that case the address of your peer is reachable, but anything else isn't. IP is complex and you can never tell if something is reachable without actually trying it.

Comment: Thanks Mirek. Ok so what I am seeing is that if I use an ip address the device always thinks it is reachable, even if that ip address does not exist on the internet via 3g. But when I provide a hostname which is available to wifi but not 3G. It reports it is not reachable via 3G because it cannot resolve the DNS. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. As soon as the network interface is up, it can resolve the name and has routing info it is reachable (unless there are some special cases, like connection over VPN, flight mode, etc.). There is also kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsDirect flag which says if the network is directly connected to one of your interfaces. I guess you will get that when connected to the same Wifi as the server.